# How to retrieve objects details of a secondary type using an array of pointers to that first object?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have constructed a box object where at construction, I save a pointer to each one into an array one by one up to a total of 81.

```
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {

        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {

            Box *currentBox;
            fin >> b;

            if (b != 0)
            {
                currentBox = new Box();
                ptrArr[iteration++] = currentBox;

            }
```

Then I used the same array to group and construct those grouped boxes as an individual object where the groups include longitudal, latitudal and sectional. I achieved this by iterating through the array in certain unique orders, saving the freshly ordered boxes into different arrays of box pointer type and then saving those into 3 different arrays of boxGroup pointer types.

```
    Box* Latitude[9];
    Box* Longitude[9];

nextLine = 0;
int longIndex=0, longCounter=0, latIndex = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
        longIndex = nextLine;
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {
            Latitude[y] = ptrArr[latIndex];
            Longitude[y] = ptrArr[longIndex];
            longIndex = longIndex + 9;
            latIndex++;
        }
        nextLine++;
        latitudes[x] = new BoxGroup(Latitude);
        longitudes[x] = new BoxGroup(Longitude);
    }
```

Now I need to somehow  input the index number of the required box and retrieve which longitude/latitude/section it is in. At the end, I will need to retrieve the elements in each one of those boxgroup objects and save them in a vector and do this for each box object since each one will have a different combination on longitude,latitude and section. The BoxGroup object is an array of pointers of Box type. How is it possible to achieve this or would you have a different approach on it ?

Comment: What fields does a Box object contain? Why does it not contain both latitude and longitude and if it does, why do you need two arrays?

Comment: The Box object contains a vector an int and a bool. I have the arrays because I need to group the box objects in a certain fashion to later on use those groups to remove items from the vector of each box object. Latitude and longitude could be thought of as columns and rows on a 9x9 grid.